# Svelte "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLProgressElement'"

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm new to coding and I have no clue what tiggers this error. I'm using svelte and the VSCode returns no error but the site doesn't load and leaves this error message on the inspect console.

```
index.mjs:207 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 
'HTMLProgressElement': The provided double value is non-finite.
    at Object.create [as c] (index.mjs:207)
    at create_component (index.mjs:1380)
    at Object.create [as c] (progress.svelte:7)
    at init (index.mjs:1472)
    at new App (App.svelte:6)
    at main.js:3
    at main.js:
```

The two files App and Progress goes as follows
app:

```
import { Router, Link, Route } from "svelte-routing";
import Navbar from './template/navbar.svelte';
import Progress from "./template/progress.svelte";
  let y 
</script>
<svelte:window bind:scrollY = {y}/>
<Navbar></Navbar>
<Progress></Progress>
<div class="main">

</div>
<style>
  .main{
    margin-top: 125px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
</style>
```

and Progress:

```
<script>
import { tweened } from 'svelte/motion';
import { cubicOut } from 'svelte/easing';
let y
  const progress = tweened(0, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: cubicOut
    });
</script>
<svelte:window bind:scrollY={y}/>
<progress value={y/500}></progress>
<style>
      progress{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 79%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    height: 25px;
    
  }
</style>
```

Sorry  if this posts sucks btw. I'm dumb.

Comment: You might want to console log the value of `y`, it might not be a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you're setting the value of the progress to `undefined / 500` initially. This apparently triggers a runtime errors that breaks the state of the app (by abruptly interrupting Svelte's operation in its middle).

Initialize your `y` variable to fix it:

```js
let y = 0
```